# Using Existing Repository With New Installation of Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a Subversion repository on a drive separated from my system drive (Windows 7) - E:\repo

I have re-installed Windows and am about to re-install Subversion (on C:).

Do I have to perform some kind of export of the existing repo, or can I just start using it?

If the latter, do I need to run any commands to configure Subversion such that it is aware of the location of the repository on my E:\ drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start use (if you didn't big "version jump", can't recall versions numbers with compatibility issues from a head).

Yes, you have to configure fresh Subversion, if you want to use svn:// of http:// access-protocols

Comment: How do I "tell" Subversion the location of the existing repo?

Comment: @onefootswill - it depends... for svnserve and Apache you have to have different settings, you have to select access method first

Comment: OK. I will see how I go tonight. I will use the same version of Subversion. I use svnserve. If I cannot figure out how to access the existing repository, I'll report back. I forgot to mention that I am running it on Windows.

Comment: @onefootswill - "Running svnserve" part in [Svnserve Based Server](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html) TortoiseSVN docs

Comment: I think I have inadvertantly told Subversion that my root directory is somewhere other than E:\repo. When I type svn://localhost at the repo browser, it says no repository is found there. The service is running. How can I change that root directory for repos?

Comment: @onefootswill if you **not** defined --root, then > Assuming your repository is located in c:\repos\TestRepo, and your server is called localhost, enter:

svn://localhost/repos/TestRepo

Comment: @onefootswill "the --root switch is also needed if your repository is located on a different partition or drive than the location of svnserve on your server"  TortoiseSVN docs. Kill active process and run new, correct

Comment: svn://localhost/repo still located nothing. I couldn't find the process to kill. Even using Process Explorer. But I could stop the service. The repo is on a different drive to the svnserve process.

Comment: @onefootswill - you have to remove (?) old service and create new, if you can't add --root switch to installed service

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. Found the service this morning in Process Explorer. Deleted it using 'sc delete svnserve'. Re-created it with the --root flag pointing to my existing repo.

Thanks Lazy Badger!